# Inheritance between nested classes

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, nested-class

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how inheritance works when it comes to nested classes, I've read a couple of good questions here on SO, but there's something I don't get yet.

To be more specific, I would expect this example

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new O().new J();
    }
}

class O{
    O(){System.out.println("O");}
    class I extends O{I(){System.out.println("I");}}
    class J extends I{J(){System.out.println("J");}}  //compile time error here
}
```

to run and print `OOIJ`, while I get this compile time error on class `J` definition: `No enclosing instance of type O is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation`.

I understand that this is somehow due to the fact that nested class `J` needs an instance of `O` to exist before it being initialized, but I think I'm missing some detail about the *instantiation chain* that takes place when I try to create a `J` object.

Why is that happening? Why does changing `I`'s definition to

```
    class I {I(){System.out.print("I");}}
```

avoid any compile time error and print `OIJ` as I would expect?

## EDIT:

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-c) thread only answers my first question:

> **Why is that happening?**
>
> Because J's superclass is itself an inner class I, thus making
>   J's default constructor illegal since it requires an enclosing
>   instance to be supplied to the constructor.

But the second question remain unanswered to me:

> **Why does changing `I`'s definition to**
>
> ```
>     class I {I(){System.out.print("I");}}
> ```
>
> **avoid any compile time error and print `OIJ` as I would expect?**

Shouldn't the problem be still there? `J`'s superclass is still a inner class, so why is it compiling now?

## Notes

**Furthermore_1**, if I declare `I` and `J` method-local

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new O().foo();
    }
}

class O{
    O(){System.out.print("O");}
    void foo(){
        class I extends O{I(){System.out.print("I");}}
        class J extends I{J(){System.out.print("J");}}
        new J();
    }
}
```

nothing *bad* happens and it prints `OOIJ`, as expected.

**Furthermore_2**, if I declare `I` and `J` static

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new O.J();
    }
}

class O{
    O(){System.out.print("O");}
    static class I extends O{I(){System.out.print("I");}}
    static class J extends I{J(){System.out.print("J");}}
}
```

I get `OIJ`, as expected.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177725/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-perfhelper-is-available-due-to-some-intermediate-c

Comment: already done, but "[inner] can only exist when an instance of outer exists" is not a satisfying answer to my curiosity

Comment: Actually I tried to copy and run your first example and it printed out "OOIJ" (each character on new line of course), I did not have compile or runtime errors...

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: @libik I'm working on Java 8

Comment: Yes, I am using Java 1.8

Comment: Something strange is happening here...

Comment: Maybe your IDE is not working correctly and think it is uncompilable while it is... What do you use? I tried it on netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis take a look at my edit. What do you think?

Comment: You second question is solved because the error included `due to some intermediate constructor invocation`. There are no more intermediate constructors. It is invoking `I()` and that by itself is a class with no superclass to address.

Comment: @Arijoon that's not really clear to me, to be honest... Why don't you post an answer that we can discuss further?

Comment: I was going to but the question has been marked duplicated so can't post anything unfortunately.

Comment: I was meant to say `I`'s constructor was the intermediate constructor between `O` and `J`. If `I` doesn't inherit from `O` it's no longer the intermediate and is the superclass itself

Comment: Ok, that's the intuitive answer, but WHY is that a problem? The error message is clear, but what's happening behind the scenes? Why is it a problem having an intermediate constructor? Anyway, I'll probably post another question about this and I'll link it here